# Resque can't update objects - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

I am trying to make a simple import background job to import some csv information using resque.

The job runs, but once I edit an object it seems like its ruined or something...

Once this job runs, it finds the user with the first lin... then at @user.name it doesn't get set, and then it can't save.  I can run this code in my console and it works great, only broken in resque.  Is there a limitation that you can't work with object or write to a database with resque?  wasted 6 hours so far trying myriads of things...please help.

```
def self.perform(chunk)
    chunk.each do |i|
        @user = User.where(:email => i[:email].to_s).first_or_initialize
        @user.name = i[:name].to_s
        if @user.save
            puts @user.email
            entity = Entity.find_by_email_domain(@user.email)
            eur = EntityUser.where(:entity_id => entity.id, :user_id => @user.id).first_or_initialize
            if eur.save
                puts "Start: BLARGITY End"
                topic = Topic.where(:number => i[:course_number].to_s).first_or_initialize
                eu = TopicUser.where(:topic_id => topic.id, :user_id => user.id, :role_i => 1).first_or_initialize
            else
                eu = TopicUser.where(:topic_id => topic.id, :user_id => user.id).first_or_initialize
            end
        eu.save
        end
    end

 end

end
```

I just tried with doing a find instead like this, and you can see the error now..

NoMethodError: undefined method `name=' for nil:NilClass

```
    @user = User.find_by_email(i[:email])
    puts "sdfdsf"
    @user.name = i[:name]
    puts @user.name
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using smarter_csv to send in 'chunk' which was a hash.  I guess when redis serializes a hash, you need to symbolize it before you start using it again.

```
chunk.each do |i|
        i.symbolize_keys!
        @user = User.find_by_email(i[:email])
        @user.name = i[:name]
```

works after symbolizing it!